# Неудачная установка apache-ant-1.8.4: Unable to locate tools.jar

Tags: linux, apache, установка, solaris

Я действовал согласно [Installing Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html). Распаковал архив apache-ant-1.8.4.tar.gz в папку /usr. Затем ввел следующие 2 команды

```
export ANT_HOME=/usr/apache-ant-1.8.4  export export PATH=${PATH}:${ANT_HOME}/bin
```

(Правда в первый раз сделал опечатку в первой команде и ввел `export ANT_HOME=/usr/apche-ant-1.8.4` и ввел эти две команды снова). После ввода `ant -version` получил

> `Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.6.0/lib/tools.jarApache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решило

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_06
```